# Reading a list in javascript

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list-view, rest, client-object-model

I have a list which i want to fetch at the front end using javascript
based on some user inputs.

The list has 3 columns - 'Name', 'Branch' and 'Age', and the list is named 'Students'.

Now if the user wants to know the students under a particular branch then i have to fetch them dynamically and show it to the end user.

Please suggest me what should be done.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code snippet to achieve your functionality, here i have used ECMA script to access sharepoint list data. [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185007(v=office.14).aspx) is the msdn link for the same.

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(GetStudentsData, "sp.js");

function GetStudentsData() {
  context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  lstStudents = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Students');
  web = context.get_web();
  currentUser = web.get_currentUser();
  context.load(currentUser);
  context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccessMethod),
                          Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailureMethod)); 
}
function onSuccessMethod(sender, args) {
   var camlStudentsQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

   // Pass your input parameters from page and you can pass those parameters through query
   camlStudentsQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name="Branch"
                                                /></IsNotNull></Where></Query></View>');
   this.StudentsListItems = lstStudents.getItems(camlStudentsQuery);
   context.load(StudentsListItems);
   context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.showStudentData),
                          Function.createDelegate(this,  
   this.onFailureMethod));
}
function showStudentData()
{
// do your job here.
}
function onFailureMethod()
{
   // catch error here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options

Options 1 : If you are using SP 2013 you can use OData which is very good with jQuery. Documentation for it is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385.aspx

Options 2 : Otherwise you use codeplex project http://spservices.codeplex.com/

Both of above can work with jQuery and also help you to CRUD functions very gracefully